# pymysql insert only if not exists

Tags: python, mysql, sql

its my first time using sql and im trying to insert data only if the entry is not in the db. My sql looks like this:

```
    insert_query = ("IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `follows` WHERE `id_user` = '"+user_id+"' AND `id_folgt` = '"+folgt_id+"') BEGIN INSERT INTO `follows`(`id_user`, `id_folgt`) VALUES ('"+user_id+"','"+folgt_id+"')END;")
```

unfortunately im getting out a syntax error

Comment: Can you post details of the syntax error please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a row only when such row not exists in the table then you have a lot of options:

1. Create unique index by an expression which is used to detect the presence. Server will forbid insertion if the value of this expression is already present in the table.
2. Use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with fake UPDATE action (for example, `id = id`, where `id` is primary key).
3. Use INSERT .. SELECT with according WHERE NOT EXISTS. The insertion will be performed only when the WHERE clause returns TRUE.

There are more options...